# extract variable from chrome console for later use in unit tests

Tags: typescript, google-chrome

I have a third party API generating a complex typescript object. I can print the object in the javascript console but it contains multiple arrays that are 500 elements. I'd like to use the object in a unit test. H

How can I extract or serialize the object so I can load into my unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on any place in the console content, and choose "Save as...", as shown in the next figure

[image]

Source - https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000222881-save-google-chrome-browser-s-console-file